# radio with custom input in alpacajs with jsonschema?

Tags: jsonschema, alpacajs

I'm trying to create a field with several radio input options and an optional fill in the blank. The following schema doesn't seem to work in displaying output:

```
{
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "enum": [
                "Option 1",
                "Option 2",
                "Option 3"
            ]
        }, {
            "type":"string"
        }
    ]
}
```

What should I be doing? Thanks!

Clarification: I'd like to output:

```
( ) option 1
( ) option 2
( ) option 3
(X) custom [__fill in the blank here__]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry it was my mistake I accidently overrided that fiddle. Thank you for your clarification. If you want to have that layout in your page you must use two different components, a radio group buttons and a simple text field that automatically will be appended after the radio group (but you could do better using jquery and append it in a different place in the **postRender** function of Alpaca. So your `schema` must be like this :

```
"schema": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "oneOf": {
      "required": true,
      "enum": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    },
    "customResponse": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

I added more options for the fields like disabling default sorting, disabling the input text for custom response because it must be enabled only when the user choose the 4th option.

Here's a more complete [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/r43g0o9e/).

Comment: Looks great! I was hoping that Alpaca/JSON Schema would have a more "built-in" way to do this without all the custom code but this works. The output type of `{"oneOf":"custom","customResponse":"Custom value here"}` is less simple than a pure string but can be easily filtered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your schema properties should be enclosed into a properties object and if the "oneOf" refers to the group of radio buttons it should be an object not an array.

```
"properties": {
  "oneOf": {
    "required": true,
    "enum": ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
  }, ////
```

Here's a complete [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/ggtg7jsc/), hope it helps.
Tell me if you want something else.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The fiddle doesn't seem to have updated? I forked the slider example I found at the link and tried to follow your instructions:  https://jsfiddle.net/24zcpgty/ 

I'm probably doing it wrong but it outputs a blank input. To be specific, I'd like to output:

    (  ) option 1
    (  ) option 2
    (  ) option 3
    (X) custom [__fill in the blank here__]